# Convoluting a large filter in GPGPU

Tags: image-processing, filtering, gpgpu, convolution

I wish to apply a certain 2D filter to 2D images, however, the filter size is huge. Image dimensions are about 2000x2000 and the filter size is about 500*500.

No, I cannot do this in frequency domain so FFT is no go. I'm aware of normal GPU convolution and the use of shared memory for coalescing memory access, however shared memory doesn't seem feasible since the space needed by the filter is large and would therefore need to be divided, this might even prove to be very complex to write.

Any ideas?

Comment: The filter is not a plain static filter, its rather a function that is data dependent. However the image memory access model is in the same fashion as that of a normal filter.

Comment: My intended algorithm is very similar to Local Histogram Equalization http://angeljohnsy.blogspot.com/2011/06/local-histogram-equalization.html (a data dependent function, however its needs to run over the image in a local window fashion)

Comment: First pass takes first neighbours, second pass takes second far neighbours and 250th pass takes 250-far neighbours into action. You can fit those frames into local memory. This is as simple as adding and subtracting "1" and "length" from the index to choose a neighbour. You need to read all the variable only once from global memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily manage doing filtering for such sized images. You can transfer hundreds of megabytes to the videomemory. Such size is going to be working well.

You can use byte matrices to transfer the image data then you can use your filter to operate on it.